# Is this question about vectors faulty?

Tags: vectors, inner-products

> Suppose that $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are three non-coplanar vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let the components of a vector $\mathbf{s}$ along $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ be $4$, $3$ and $5$, respectively. If the components of $\mathbf{s}$ along $-\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$, $\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$ and $-\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$ are $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively, then the value of $2x+y+z$ is _______.

This is a question from an entrance exam (JEE Advanced 2015). In the official answer key, all candidates were awarded the points for this question which led me to guess that the question is somehow incorrect or has information missing. The only problem I can see is that $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are not mentioned to be mutually perpendicular, otherwise we could have written $\mathbf{s}=4\dfrac{\mathbf{p}}{|\mathbf{p}|}+3\dfrac{\mathbf{q}}{|\mathbf{q}|}+5\dfrac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|}$, but we would still not be able to proceed because $-\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$, $\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$ and $-\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$ aren't guaranteed to be mutually perpendicular.

My question is, I need a mathematical explanation that either:

- The problem is inconsistent.
- The problem has more than one correct answer.
- A crucial piece of information is missing.

  *Basically, I need to know why this question is faulty.*

  **EDIT 1**: I accepted the answer of user @DanielCunha because it was understandable at my level and the answer offered a pretty reasonable alternative to what could have been.  However I feel that the bounty should be awarded to user @mweiss because they put more time and effort into answering the problem and making it easier for me to understand, as is evidenced by this post: [Reference request: A primer on the difference between "Vectors" in linear algebra vs. "Vectors" in ohysics/vector calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464452/reference-request-a-primer-on-the-difference-between-vectors-in-linear-algebr)

Comment: If you want check the perpendicularity start by cross producting them

Comment: On solving for $x,y,z$, we get $x=-4p+3q+5r, y=4p-3q+5r, z=-4p-3q+5r$. So, $2x+y+z$ is dependent on $p,r$ which is missing.

Comment: @RiverX15 which equations did you solve?

Comment: @insipidintegrator Component of $\vec a$ along $\vec b=\frac{\vec a\cdot\vec b}{|\vec b|}$ so I obtained the values of $\vec s\cdot\vec p, \vec s\cdot\vec q, \vec s\cdot\vec r$ in terms of $p,q,r$ and hence $x,y,z$.

Comment: Hey @RiverX15 I am still not sure. I got $\vec s$• $\vec p$ = 4p, $\vec s$•$\vec q$ = 3q, $\vec s$•$\vec r$ = 5r  Also, $\vec s$•($\vec -p$ + $\vec q$ + $\vec r$) = -4p+3q+5r = x| ($\vec -p$ + $\vec q$ + $\vec r$)| , $\vec s$•($\vec p$  $\vec -q$ + $\vec r$) = 4p-3q+5r = y| ($\vec p$  $\vec -q$ + $\vec r$)| , and finally  $\vec s$•($\vec -p$ $\vec -q$ + $\vec r$) = -4p-3q+5r = z| ($\vec -p$  $\vec -q$ + $\vec r$)|.       How do you solve this system?

Comment: @insipidintegrator I did not solve anything. Just evaluated the value of $2x+y+z$ which came out to be dependent on $p,q,r$. So the question must be incomplete.

Comment: @RiverX15 look at my second comment. I think you have made a mistake by ignoring the terms which are multiplied with x, y and z, like |p—q+r| etc.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Oops! Sorry I just realised where I am going wrong. Probably the question is incomplete due to non availability of the values of **p,q,r**.

Comment: "3 non-co-planar vectors"? Any 3 points in $\Bbb R^3$ lie in a plane.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet any two free vectors must be coplanar, but three vectors (like i, j, k) need not.

Comment: @insipidintegrator.  The Q is apparently not using the standard definitions.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet How? I don’t see any problem with three non-coplanar vectors.

Comment: I take "non-coplanar" to mean, not all lying in the same plane through the origin.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why through the origin? My understanding of “non coplanar” is not all lying on the same plane. How does the origin come into the picture?

Comment: The problem starts by positing three non-coplanar vectors in ${\bf R}^3$. By your understanding, the problem is already nonsense from the first sentence, and we can all go home. I'm giving you an alternative reading, under which the problem at any rate passes the first hurdle, even if it falls down later. Another way to think of it: the difference between a plane through the origin and a plane not through the origin is that the former is a vector space, the latter, not. So we take non-coplanar to mean, not generating a proper subspace of ${\bf R}^3$. Continued...

Comment: Yet another way to see it: you are thinking of a vector as a point in 3-space. But one could think of a vector as a line segment joining the origin to a point in 3-space. Then non-coplanar means the three line segments don't all lie in a single plane.

Comment: Yes I agree @GerryMyerson I just meant to say that the initial point of all the vectors may lie on any other point rather than the origin, but I get that it’s not a significant point to fuss about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For given linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^3$, we have:

$\frac{p_1}{\|\mathbf{p}\|}\,s_1 + \frac{p_2}{\|\mathbf{p}\|}\,s_2 + \frac{p_3}{\|\mathbf{p}\|}\,s_3 = 4$

$\frac{q_1}{\|\mathbf{q}\|}\,s_1 + \frac{q_2}{\|\mathbf{q}\|}\,s_2 + \frac{q_3}{\|\mathbf{q}\|}\,s_3 = 3$

$\frac{r_1}{\|\mathbf{r}\|}\,s_1 + \frac{r_2}{\|\mathbf{r}\|}\,s_2 + \frac{r_3}{\|\mathbf{r}\|}\,s_3 = 5$

This system has a unique solution, so $\mathbf{s}$ is well defined in the problem, it is a known function of the unit vectors in the directions $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$.

However, this does not mean that $2\,x + y + z$ can be obtained as a scalar value, independent of $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$. As it is, if there is a solution, the resolution seems to be cumbersome.

---

Since they removed the question, I agree that there must be something wrong. One possibility is that the people who proposed this question were considering that everything was defined as projections of the other vectors along $\mathbf{s}$, instead of projections of $\mathbf{s}$ along the other vectors ($\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$, $\mathbf{r}$, $-\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$, $\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$ and $-\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$).

In this case, assuming valid vectors for $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$, the resolution is very direct:

$p_1\,s_1 + p_2\,s_2 + p_3\,s_3 = 4\,\|\mathbf{s}\|$

$q_1\,s_1 + q_2\,s_2 + q_3\,s_3 = 3\,\|\mathbf{s}\|$

$r_1\,s_1 + r_2\,s_2 + r_3\,s_3 = 5\,\|\mathbf{s}\|$

Therefore

$x = -4+3+5 = 4$

$y = 4-3+5 = 6$

$z = -4-3+5 = -2$

$2\,x + y + z = 8 + 6 - 2 = 12$

---

Note that there exist valid solutions for this, e.g.:

$\mathbf{p} = [4\,\sqrt{3},0,0]$

$\mathbf{q} = [0,3\,\sqrt{3},0]$

$\mathbf{r} = [0,0,5\,\sqrt{3}]$

$\mathbf{s} = [1,1,1]$

Comment: Now  that I've seen @mweiss answer, I believe that the question was just remove because of this ambiguity of the "component" word.

Comment: Does T in your examples stand for transpose, as in, you want to write a column vector?

Comment: By the way @DanielCunha you guess is pretty reasonable and realistic ! (+1)

Comment: @insipidintegrator Yes, 'T' stands for transpose, force of habit. It is not relevant here, I've just removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:**

The OP is (perhaps reasonably) interpreting "component" in the vector calculus sense, in which "the component of $\mathbf{v}$ in the direction $\mathbf{w}$" means $\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}}{\| \mathbf{w} \|}$, but I think the intent of the problem is to think of "component" in the linear algebra sense, i.e. as the coefficients of a vector relative to a basis (which need not be orthogonal nor orthonormal).  Probably the problem was discarded precisely because of this ambiguity.

**Full explanation:**

Perpendicularity has nothing to do with this problem.  The key concept is *linear independence*.  The statement

> Suppose that $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are three non-coplanar vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

is, I can only assume, a somewhat informal and imprecise way of saying that these three vectors are linearly independent.  (See below for more on this...)

Because of the linear independence, any vector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb R^3$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination $a\mathbf{p} + b\mathbf{q} + c\mathbf{r}$.  We are told

> Let the components of a vector $\mathbf{s}$ along $\mathbf{p}$,
> $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ be $4$, $3$ and $5$, respectively

which means that $\mathbf{s} = 4\mathbf{p} + 3\mathbf{q} + 5\mathbf{r}$.

Now it is an interesting fact, which can be proven (consider this a side quest, if you will) that if $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are linearly independent, then so too are the three vectors
$$\mathbf{w_1} = -\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$$
$$\mathbf{w_2} = \mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$$
$$\mathbf{w_3} = -\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}$$
which means that any vector $\mathbf{v}$ can also be written uniquely as a linear combination of $\mathbf{w_1}, \mathbf{w_2}$ and $\mathbf{w_3}$.  We are told that the components of $\mathbf{s}$ along these vectors are $x, y, z$, which means that $\mathbf{s} = x\mathbf{w_1} + y\mathbf{w_2} + z\mathbf{w_3}$.

Equating these two representations together, we get

$$4\mathbf{p} + 3\mathbf{q} + 5\mathbf{r} = x(-\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}) + y(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r}) + z(-\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{r})$$

Collecting like terms on the right hand side, we end up with the equation
$$4\mathbf{p} + 3\mathbf{q} + 5\mathbf{r} = (-x+y-z)\mathbf{p} + (x-y-z)\mathbf{q} + (x+y+z)\mathbf{r}$$

Now because the vectors are linearly independent, the components on the left must exactly match the components on the right; that is, the values of $x, y, z$ must satisfy the system of equations
$$-x + y - z = 4$$
$$x - y - z = 3$$
$$x + y + z = 5$$

This system has a unique solution, so we can unambiguously determine the values of $x, y$ and $z$, and hence calculate $2x + y + z$ as well.

So as far as I can tell, there is no fundamental problem with the question.

HOWEVER:
As I briefly alluded to at the start of the problem, referring to the three vectors as "non-coplanar" (instead of "linearly independent", which is what the problem posers presumably intended) is both not standard and potentially misleading.  It is commonplace to identify vectors with points, and (as user @DanielWainfleet observed in the comments under the OP)  "any 3 points in $\mathbb R^3$ lie in a plane".  So if you interpret the problem that way, the question makes no sense from the very beginning.  I can only assume that this is the reason why they decided to accept all answers as correct: they realized, belatedly, that in choosing the informal phrase "non-coplanar" over the more precise "linearly independent", they were opening themselves up to an unintended second interpretation of the question, one in which it had no solution because the premise was impossible.

Comment: I need some clarifications: 1)Can you provide me with some reference(extremely basic level) where it explains how/why “if three vectors $\vec p$, $ \vec q$ and $ \vec r$ are linearly independent and the components of $\vec s$ along $\vec p$, $\vec q$, $\vec r$ are a,b,c then $\vec s$=a $\vec p$+b $\vec q$+c $\vec r$. I suspect that I may have a huge conceptual gap here.  2) Can you provide some really basic reference as to the difference between components in linear algebra and vector calculus(yes, I interpreted it as you guessed).

Comment: I say that I may have some conceptual gap because it makes sense to me only if $ \vec p$, $ \vec q$, $ \vec r$ are  mutually perpendicular and then too, I would write $ \vec s$= a$\hat p$+b$\hat q$+ c$\hat r$, not $\vec s$=a $\vec p$+b $\vec q$+c $\vec r$ because the lengths of the individual vectors are not mentioned.

Comment: Basically, why do you use $\vec p$ instead of $\hat p$ everywhere?

Comment: @insipidintegrator have you ever taken a course in abstract linear algebra? Do you know what a “basis” is?

Comment: I’ll be honest. I don’t even know the difference between “linear algebra” and “abstract linear algebra”. I’m a high school student.

Comment: Let me try again:: have you ever seen an example of a vector space that is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but I don’t know what a subspace means (is it a subset?) and have only a very slight whiff of what a vector space means. Also I have never dealt with $\mathbb R^n$ with $n \gt 3$.

Comment: BUT, I know what linearly independent means. As for ‘basis’, I have a fuzzily clear idea.

Comment: @insipidintegrator, concerning 1) - That is the _definition_ of the components. Rather, it's one possible definition.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I think this is going to be difficult to explain in this format (certainly not in the comments, and probably not in an answer, either). I think you need to read up on vector space fundamentals first.

Comment: @mr_e_man and mweiss can you please explain why unit vectors  are  not being used? Like I have asked in the second comment. Yes, now I have read up a bit on vector spaces.

Comment: In a generalized vector space “length” does not exist as a well-defined concept, so “unit vectors” aren’t a thing, and a coordinate system is determined by *any* spanning set of linearly independent vectors.

Comment: Thanks @mweiss  (+50)