# Reference request: A primer on the difference between "Vectors" in linear algebra vs. "Vectors" in ohysics/vector calculus

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces, vectors

(This question is inspired by [a recent question on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4461221/is-this-question-about-vectors-faulty).)

The word "vector" means different things in different contexts.  Most students who encounter the term first learn it in the context of $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$, often when learning Physics applications.  In this setting, a vector can be thought of as a quantity with both a magnitude and a direction; position, velocity, and force are all fundamental examples of vectors.  Later, students might also encounter "vector fields" (like, for example, an electric field), which can be thought of as "a vector at every point in space", but the basic notion of "a directed magnitude" remains applicable.  Vector operations in this setting include addition, scalar multiplication, dot product, and (in three dimensions) cross product.

The word "vector" means something quite different in linear algebra.  In this context, we don't define "vector", and never ask questions like "Is [fill-in-the-blank] a vector?"  Instead, the object of attention is the **vector space**, which is a set that has various algebraic properties.  The "things" in the set can be directed magnitudes, but they can also be functions, matrices, infinite sequences, or many other types of objects.  Operations in this setting include addition and scalar multiplication, but *not* (in general) a dot product or a cross product; moreover vectors in an abstract vector space do not have magnitude or direction (unless and until you choose an inner product for your space, at which point it becomes an inner product space).

The difference between these settings, and the fact that students typically come into a first course in linear algebra having already seen vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$, means that students have some intuitions about vectors before they know what a vector space is.  Some of these intuitions are useful, while others are unhelpful and need to be unlearned.

My question:  Is there a good, short primer that focuses specifically on the **differences** between these two perspectives on what "vector" means?  To clarify:  I am not just asking for a brief introduction to abstract vector spaces (the internet abounds with those, and every linear algebra textbook contains such an introduction).  Rather, I am looking for a short, self-contained document that focuses specifically on **what students need to unlearn about vectors in order to succeed in linear algebra**.

(It occurs to me, by the way, that there are probably other discipline-specific notions of "vector" as well. I believe for some data scientists a "vector" is simply a one-dimensional array, of arbitrary length, whose entries can be of any data type.  The "length" of a vector in this sense is simply the number of entries it contains.  I am not sure if there are other notions of "vector" floating around out there, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are.)

Comment: I find this Wikipedia article useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector Maybe it is more important to know what it *does* than what it *is* to learn linear algebra.